# AngularJs two way data binding doesn't work when add SignalR lib

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

My problem started when I tried to add a library SignalR in my AngularJs project. I do not know why but the data flow has stopped working properly, I mean that when I try to insert an object into an array I do not see it, but when I try to add another one I see first object, and when I try to add a third object I see only the second.

edit : all code in the angular controller.

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'HttpSrv', '$state', function ($scope, HttpSrv, $state) {
$scope.messages = [];

activate();

function activate() {
    if (HttpSrv.CheckToken()) {
        loadPage();
    }
};

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    con.stop();
});

function connectToChat() {

    HttpSrv.http('GET', 'home/GetChatToken').then(function (res) {
        localStorage.setItem('ChatToken', res.Result);
        con.start({ jsonp: true }, function () { console.log('Start'); });
    });
}



var con = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:4704/");
var hub = con.createHubProxy('ChatHub');

hub.on('fail', function (res) {
    console.error(res);
});

hub.on('addMessage', addMessage);

$scope.trySend = function () {
    hub.invoke('SendMessage', localStorage.getItem('ChatToken'), document.getElementById('messageBox').value);
};

function addMessage(name, message, elementId) {
    var tempMessage = '<li id="' + elementId + '" class="right clearfix"><div class="chat-body clearfix">'
    tempMessage += '<div class="header"><strong class="pull-left primary-font">' + name + ':  </strong> <br />'
    tempMessage += '</div><p>' + message + '</p></div></li>'

    document.getElementById('chatBody').innerHTML += tempMessage;
    document.getElementById('messageBox').value = '';
    document.getElementById(elementId).scrollIntoView();
    document.getElementById('chatBody').focus();
}

function loadPage() {
    HttpSrv.http('GET', 'home/get').then(function (res) {
        //console.log(res);
        if (res.Status == 200 && res.Succeeded) {
            connectToChat();
            for (var i = 0; i < res.ListResult.length; i++) {
                res.ListResult[i].CreateDate = res.ListResult[i].CreateDate.replace('T', ' ').slice(0, 19);
            }
            $scope.newsList = res.ListResult;

        }
    });
};}]);
```

(i use document.getElementById because of the problem)

Comment: Could you please include the code, or at least provide an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: So this is your work around, but where is the code of the originial problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be building markup in your code.  Simply add the message to the list and use ng-repeat in your markup.

However, you also must make sure you use $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest() when you are processing messages from signalR.

```
function addMessage(name, message, elementId) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.messages.push(message);
    });
}
```